# How to make query for Many-to-Many Relation using Parse.com database?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I can't seem to figure out how to make a proper query for a many-to-many relation. I have two classes:

- _User (standard)
- Group

A user can be a member of multiple groups, and a group can have multiple users.
In the User class i created a relation to the Group class: |_groups (group)|.

I want to make a query to get all the groups where the current (logged-in) user is a member of. I already read the Developer Guide, but i just cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

*> edit:*

> I figured it out:
>
> ```
> ParseObject current = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); //get current user
> ParseRelation relation = current.getRelation("groups"); //select the relation
> ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery(); //get all relations
> ```

Comment: I think we need to see the schema before answering.

Comment: There is nothing extra in the classes. The only thing I added to _User is the Relation with Group. In the Group class the name of the group is stored in group_name as a string.